# Gridview width is going outside boundry bcz content width is larger

Tags: c#, .net, gridview

```
     <div style="padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 15px; padding-bottom: 25px">
    <div class="table">
       <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="gvList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
      DataKeyNames="UserId" AllowSorting="true" onrowcreated="gvList_RowCreated" 
     onrowdatabound="gvList_RowDataBound" 
     onsorting="gvList_Sorting">
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="even" />
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                     Records for selected criteria do not exist
                </EmptyDataTemplate>

                 <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemStyle Width="2%"/>
       <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblSelect" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LBShowcaseRes,lblSelect %>"></asp:Label>
       </HeaderTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>

       <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemStyle width="15%"/>
       <HeaderTemplate>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFirstName" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LBShowcaseRes,lblFirstName %>" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="FirstName"></asp:LinkButton>
       </HeaderTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>   

       <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemStyle Width="18%"/>
       <HeaderTemplate>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkLastName" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LBShowcaseRes,lblLastName %>" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="LastName"></asp:LinkButton>
       </HeaderTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("LastName") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>   

       <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemStyle Width="20%"/>
       <HeaderTemplate>
              <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEmailId" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LBShowcaseRes,lblEmailid %>" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="EmailAddress"></asp:LinkButton>
       </HeaderTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="lblEmailId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmailAddress") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField> 

       <asp:TemplateField> 
       <ItemStyle Width="15%" />
       <HeaderTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LBShowcaseRes,lblUserName %>"></asp:Label>
       </HeaderTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserName") %>' MaxLength="75" Width="100px" EnableViewState="true"></asp:TextBox>
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>  

       <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
       <HeaderTemplate>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkOffice" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LBShowcaseRes,lblOffice %>" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="OfficeName"></asp:LinkButton>
       </HeaderTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="lblOffice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OfficeName") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>

       <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemStyle Width="20%" />
       <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblRolePrompt" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LBShowcaseRes,lblRole %>"></asp:Label>
       </HeaderTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnRole" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("RoleName") %>' />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRole" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                </asp:DropDownList>
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

        </div>


        <div class="table-nav">
        <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LBShowcaseRes,btnDelete %>"  SkinID="leftButton" 
            OnClientClick="var values= GetSelectedUser();return ConfirmDeleteWithValues('Please select at least one User for deletion.',values);" 
            onclick="btnDelete_Click" />              
        <asp:Button ID="btnPrintExport" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LBShowcaseRes,btnPrintRep %>" CausesValidation="false"/>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" OnClientClick="return ConfirmAddUser();"
            Text="<%$Resources:LBShowcaseRes,btnSave %>"  
            onclick="btnSave_Click" />
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my table css is
table { border-collapse: collapse; width:100%}

Now when i run the page the gridview width is going outside the 100% bcz the content width is very large...so i want to do that it should break the content after reaching the width of that column what should i do plz help me.......

modified
        
        
           
                
                    
                    
                         Records for selected criteria do not exist

```
                 <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemStyle Width="20px"/>
       <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblSelect" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LBShowcaseRes,lblSelect %>"></asp:Label>
       </HeaderTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>

       <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemStyle width="35px"/>
       <HeaderTemplate>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFirstName" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LBShowcaseRes,lblFirstName %>" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="FirstName"></asp:LinkButton>
       </HeaderTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>   

       <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemStyle Width="35px"/>
       <HeaderTemplate>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkLastName" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LBShowcaseRes,lblLastName %>" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="LastName"></asp:LinkButton>
       </HeaderTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("LastName") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>   

       <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemStyle Width="35px"/>
       <HeaderTemplate>
              <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEmailId" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LBShowcaseRes,lblEmailid %>" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="EmailAddress"></asp:LinkButton>
       </HeaderTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="lblEmailId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmailAddress") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField> 

       <asp:TemplateField> 
       <ItemStyle Width="35px" />
       <HeaderTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LBShowcaseRes,lblUserName %>"></asp:Label>
       </HeaderTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserName") %>' MaxLength="75" Width="100px" EnableViewState="true"></asp:TextBox>
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>  

       <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemStyle Width="35px" />
       <HeaderTemplate>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkOffice" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LBShowcaseRes,lblOffice %>" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="OfficeName"></asp:LinkButton>
       </HeaderTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="lblOffice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OfficeName") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>

       <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
       <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblRolePrompt" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LBShowcaseRes,lblRole %>"></asp:Label>
       </HeaderTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnRole" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("RoleName") %>' />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRole" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                </asp:DropDownList>
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

        </div>


        <div class="table-nav">
        <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LBShowcaseRes,btnDelete %>"  SkinID="leftButton" 
            OnClientClick="var values= GetSelectedUser();return ConfirmDeleteWithValues('Please select at least one User for deletion.',values);" 
            onclick="btnDelete_Click" />              
        <asp:Button ID="btnPrintExport" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LBShowcaseRes,btnPrintRep %>" CausesValidation="false"/>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" OnClientClick="return ConfirmAddUser();"
            Text="<%$Resources:LBShowcaseRes,btnSave %>"  
            onclick="btnSave_Click" />
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which content is very large!! Please mention it...

Comment: in gidview lblEmailId content

Comment: @user993634, you said lblEmailId is the largest but why you have given more width and same width as lblEmailId for some other columns. Give the max width only to the emailid and decrease the width for all the remaining.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you didn't give any width to your gridview.  Give the width of the gridview as also 100% and change the widths of each TemplateField from %'s to normal numbers according to your adjustment.

EDIT:

Then Increase the height of the grid view also, so that the data will adjust and fit to the table.

Comment: Did you changed the TemplateField width from percentage to a certain width in number?

Comment: Then change the width of grid from 100% to normal pixel numbers as said by sikender

Answer (score 0):

Set gridview width in pixels (fixed) instead of percentage. If you set width in perscentage , the gridview width will adjust with "div or table or Page width".